# Is there a way to increase line spacing in eclipse console?

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes when there are are multiple `System.out.println();` in a script in eclipse, the results when printed in console all get muddled up making it difficult to differentiate or read nicely one set of results from another. Is there a way to insert line breaks or spacing between outputs, for visibility?

UPDATED:
As suggested in comments below, adding an empty call or multilple keyboard characters to `System.out.println();` can create fne division between outputs from multiple System.out.println();. The solution worked but this has led to another concern. If the output from a SINGLE System.out.println(); look all muddled, is there a way to create spacing here e.g.

```
1 = Box xxx
ID number:  xxx
Age:    32
First occu: 09/10
Height: 141
Body type:  Athletic
Hair type:  Straight
House:  Yes
2 = Box xxx
ID number:  xxx
Age:    32
First occu: 09/10
Height: 161
Body type:  Athletic
Hair type:  Straight
House:  No
```

The above is an output from just one `sysout`from java operation:

```
for (WebElement e : list ) {
    System.out.println( e.getAttribute("innerText"));
}
```

The output contains 2 blocks of information (1 and 2). I Observed that block 1 is so close to block 2 and I dont know how to create a partition between the two, or even if it is possible.

Comment: Add empty calls to `System.out.println();`?

Comment: System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you have done so far.

Comment: Can you add a picture with the output of your console, please?

Comment: Thanks guys, adding an empty call or keybpard characters to System.out.println(); worked nice. I never thought about that. I have a similar concern, I will update the question

Comment: `for (WebElement e : list) print(e); println();`?

Comment: @cricket_007, updated

Comment: Okay, so fire an empty call to `println` after you print the inner text of that element

Comment: @cricket_007, this worked like a charm. Thanks